# how to make scrollview without xml?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-activity

I have a code like this:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val linearLayout:LinearLayout = LinearLayout(this)

        linearLayout.orientation = LinearLayout.VERTICAL

        setContentView(linearLayout)

            for (i in 0 until 35){
            val button = Button(this)
            button.text = "Button ${i+1}"
                linearLayout.addView(button)


            }
        }


        }
```

how to make scroll view?
I googled for a long time and did not find information

Comment: why you can make your activity scrollable without xml ?

Answer (score 0):

You are adding buttons to the LinerLayout, So it is not scrollable.
First you have to declare a scrollview
`val scrollView = ScrollView(this)`,
then add your LinerLayout to scrollview like this
`scrollView.addView(linearLayout)`,
Then use that ScrollView for setContentView()

Answer (score 0):

Do create of type ScrollView viewgroup object and add the single root child to it which is a linear layout in your case.

```
    val scrollView: ScrollView = ScrollView(this)
    scrollView.isFillViewport = true
    val linearLayout: LinearLayout = LinearLayout(this)

    linearLayout.orientation = LinearLayout.VERTICAL
    scrollView.addView(linearLayout)
    setContentView(scrollView)
```